# How to change the private key passphrase in lsh?

Tags: ssh, security, password, gnu, key-authentication

`info lsh` [manual](https://www.lysator.liu.se/%7Enisse/lsh/lsh.html) covers how to create a keypair and protect the private key with a passphrase. The manual does not tell how to change the passphrase or how to decode the private key, which is stored as a `password-encrypted` S-expression. Per the manual, `lsh-writekey` encrypts the private key with the passphrase. But `lsh-writekey` expects a `private-key` S-expression similar to what `lsh-keygen` provides. Otherwise, it outputs something but explains:

```
$ cat ~/.lsh/identity | lsh-writekey -o test-output-file
Enter new passphrase: 
Again: 
lsh-writekey: spki_make_signer: Expected private-key expression.
```

How do I get the existing private key as a `private-key` S-expression for `lsh-writekey`, so that I could set a new password for that private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hint at the bottom of `man lsh-writekey` that there is also `lsh-decrypt-key`. It has its own manual page. It is not covered in the Texinfo manual for some reason and is not mentioned in the `SEE ALSO` section of `man lsh`.

You need to move the existing keys or specify a different output file for `lsh-writekey` because it refuses to overwrite existing private or public key files. Here is how to change the passphrase:

```
$ mv ~/.lsh/identity ~/.lsh/identity.backup
$ mv ~/.lsh/identity.pub  ~/.lsh/identity.pub.backup
$ cat ~/.lsh/identity.backup | lsh-decrypt-key | lsh-writekey
```

You enter the current passphrase for the key and proceed with specifying the new passphrase.